# правки в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

есть ссылка вида https://lptf.it/lptf_admin/views/loginAdmin/login.php
хочу сделать такого https://lptf.it/lptf_admin/login

как это можно реализовать в htaccess

Answer (score 0):

`Alias /lptf_admin/login /full/path/to/login_dir/`

Comment: Насчет имени алиаса согласен. А если полный путь до index.php будет содержать пробел в имени какого-нибудь каталога?